# Calling functions in Object.Prototype from Object

Tags: javascript, function, prototype

I added a function to `Object.prototype` using `Object.prototype.func = function () {...}` but when I try to call it using `Object.func()` it throws an error that it is not defined in Object.

Comment: Can't be. `Object` also inherits from `Object.prototype`.

Comment: You're testing this improperly, because that should work fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everything in JavaScript is an object and inherits from Object (including Object). If there's a property on Object.prototype then EVERYTHING can access it because it is in everything's prototype.

http://jsfiddle.net/PxLDu/1/

Comment: Note that the primitives weren't objects, but were silently converted to a new object to call the method and the object was then discarded

Comment: @Adam does this include Object() itself? I want to do Object.func()

Comment: @geeko the jsfiddle has `Object.func()` right there at the end, you are doing something differently. Also see http://jsfiddle.net/9WjBr/

Answer (score 1):

Seems to be working fine for me (from node REPL):

```
Object.prototype.something = function() { console.log("Something!"); }
[Function]
> b = new Ob
Object  

Object  

> b = new Object()
{}
> b.something()
Something!
```

Comment: you are creating a new object using Object() but I'm trying to call my func from within Object() itself like Object.func() but it is not working

Comment: You mean like this: `> Object.prototype.someFunc = function() { console.log("some function"); } > Object.someFunc(); > some function`. Again, this works just fine.